# If distinct pair of numbers has Odd Product in Python

Tags: python, list, filter, mapreduce, reduce

I want to find if the Input String has Odd Product for distinct numbers:
I did this so far:

```
# To get input string into list of integer
input = [int(i) for i in input.split()]
# to get odd numbers
sequence=filter(lambda i: i % 2, sequence)
```

I want to use an operation where I can filter distinct odd numbers in a list and multiply until I get odd number and return true if the result is not odd return false.
I am new to lamda and filter.
I want to know how can I do using this in one statement in Python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.accumulate` to repeatedly apply a function (e.g. multiplication) to an iterable:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> bool(list(accumulate({int(i) for i in input().split() if int(i) % 2}, int.__mul__))[-1] % 2)
1 2 3 4 5
True
```

Answer (score 0):

For filtering distinct odd numbers in a list you can use list comprehension along with set(set is used to get distinct values).

```
input = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
input = list(set([i for i in input if i%2!=0]))  # it would give distinct odd values
```